# How to change/set priority of Azure Application Gateway rule

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm trying to set up a rule in my Azure Application Gateway which applies a longer timeout limit on certain requests to allow a service to serve requests/data without a timeout.

The rule is configured with path-based routing so it should only kick in if requests contain a specific path prefix.

I believe that my rule is not being executed however, because it sits lower down in the list of rules from the more general rule.

Is there a way to set the priority within the Azure Portal, or can this only be done when managing this configuration via power shell scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment in time you can't set rule priority through the Azure Portal for an existing Application Gateway. You will need to set a priority on **all** of your existing rules through Powershell/Azure CLI, then you will be able to manage them through the portal. Note that this only applies to Application Gateway V2.

In order to do that, you can loop over all your existing rules and set them a unique priority between 1 and 20000 (1 = highest priority, 20000=lowest priority). Here's an example of such Powershell script:

```
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant 'TENANT-GUID-HERE'
$AppGW = Get-AzApplicationGateway -Name "APP-GATEWAY-NAME-HERE" -ResourceGroupName "RESSOURCE-GROUP-HERE"
$Rules = Get-AzApplicationGatewayRequestRoutingRule -ApplicationGateway $AppGW

$i = 1000
foreach ($Rule in $Rules) {
    $Rule.Priority = $i
    $i++
}

Set-AzApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $AppGw
```

Then, if the script succeeds, you will now be able to manage rules priorities on the Portal (look for the "Priority" textbox while adding or modifying a rule).

Comment: now you can set this up in azure portal itself. As they enabled this as a mandatory field to create routing rules